# sorted() and lambda function in python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

My question is, I do not understand this lambda function to sort the xml document.
It works, but I don't get it.
The expression of the lambda is: (child.tag,child.get('volume'))  and I don't get it.

Could anyone cast some light on it?

Thanks

```
#Example of xml document
<warehouse>
    <sale product="name1" price="1">
        <idSale>1</idSale>
        <volume>10</volume>
        <store>store1</store>
    </sale>
</warehouse>

Here the python code:
#importing xml document as a tree
ree = ET.parse("warehouse.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

#sorting by volume
root[:] = sorted(root, key=lambda child: (child.tag,child.get('volume')))
```

Also, if i use as expression:
`(child.get('volume'))`
it sorts if I pass "product", but not volume...
What am I missing?

Edit:
It works only for "product".
Since volume is a child of the element "sale", how do I order for volume?

Comment: `sorted` returns a sorted list, optionally sorting by the values a `key` function maps the elements to. In this case, the `lambda` maps elements to (tag, volume). Tuples in Python are compared lexicographically, so this will first sort by tag, then by volume in the case of equal tags.

Comment: Side note: Assuming `root` is a list, this could be written cleaner (and more efficiently) by directly using `root.sort(...)` rather than `root[:] = sorted(root, ...)`.

Comment: Got it, thank you.
What if I want to order only by child.get('volume') of the child of child...?

Comment: Then use `key = lambda child: child.get('volume')` (assuming `child.get('volume')` returns a number, otherwise you'll probably want to wrap that in `int`).

Comment: It doesn't work.
It return this error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' ".

Like you can see from the xml document above, volume is the child of the child tho... Could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't know your XML library, but yes, it seems `get` gets direct children so you'd probably first have to get sale, then get the volume of that. I had assumed your existing code was correct (and you were looking for an explanation as to why it works) but apparently it isn't.

Comment: The structure of the xml file is actually in my post. It is like the 1st thing I have written xD. Maybe you missed it.

Comment: It's not about the structure of your XML, it's about which XML library you use. Going by `ET`, I assume it's [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)?

Answer (score 0):

> Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, each element must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and have the same length.
>
> If not equal, the sequences are ordered the same as their first differing elements. For example, cmp([1,2,x], [1,2,y]) returns the same as cmp(x,y). If the corresponding element does not exist, the shorter sequence is ordered first (for example, [1,2] < [1,2,3]).

For exapmle:

`(1, 2) > (3, 4)  # False`

`(1, 2) > (3, 4, 5)  # False`

`(6, 1) > (1, 10) # True`

Comment: Thank you.
Could I also pass a tuple of 3 elements like (child.tag, child.get('product'), 3rd element)
where the 3rd element is the child of the child?
Do you know how to get the child of the child?